# How to add two new cell to section and paging section?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Let's say we got 2 sections in UICollection View like this :

```
   -----------------  ----------------- -----------------
   |header section0|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer section0
   |header section1|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer section1
   -----------------  ----------------- -----------------
```

If I am going to add multi section like this (two columns in a CollectionView ):

![screenshot2][2]

```
   -------------  ---------------  -----------------   -----------------  -----------  -------
   |header sec0|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer sec0          |header section5| 0-0  | 0-1 | footer 
   |header sec1|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer sec1   ||     |header section6| 0-0  | 0-1 | footer 
   |header sec2|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer sec2   ||     |header section7| 0-0  | 0-1 | footer 
   |header sec3|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer sec3   ||     |header section8| 0-0  | 0-1 | footer 
   |header sec4|   0-0   |   0-1   |footer sec4   ||     |header section9| 0-0  | 0-1 | footer 
   -------------  ----------------- -----------------
```

I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to find a concise answer. Please help me, thanks

Comment: Welcome here! Have you tried creating custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Comment: I have tried but not working, It only displays just one column with multi-section. Would you have a suggestion?

Comment: I would suggest you find a tutorial regarding `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (or even `UICollectionViewLayout`) subsclassing. It's definitely the way to solve your problem. And it's not hard. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a vertical stack view for the section header and footer